# Why does this curve have angular shapes in the graph editor?

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

[image]

When I started adding keyframes in the graph editor for an object I noticed this strange curve shape appearing between the two values. I've tried changing to different handle types but it remains stuck like this. It doesn't seem to affect the animation though so I'm not sure what this means. Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can u check in the graph editor:

maybe you have added a Stepped modifier?

[image]

1. Choose graph editor:

[image]

2. select your object
3. select your channel

[image]

4. press "N" and click on modifiers

[image]

Comment: Thanks, don't even know how I managed to add it in the first place. xD